# Using for loop and rbind to iterate over multiple files

Tags: r, loops

I have a small R script of 14 functions and want to run it for 81 files. While I have read several posts on Stack Overflow that address similar issues, I am still having trouble getting this working. I am using a `for` loop and `rbind`.

All functions within the `{ }` of the loop work. I have tested them without the `for` loop and I get the vector of data that I need. But when I run the `for` loop I only get an output for the last file in the folder. I am not sure what is going on.

Is the `for` loop working right (is it iterating through the files) and simply overwriting the previous runs? If the `for` loop is working then I assume I have a problem with my `rbind`. Or, is the `for` loop only running the last file in `list.files()`?

In the end, I want a matrix (or table) with the results of the 14 functions for each of the 81 files.

Here is the code:

```
res=(1:14)
for(i in list.files())
{ 
  nd = read.csv(i, header= TRUE, row.names =1, check.names = FALSE)
  mx = as.matrix(nd)

  res[1]=basename(i) 
  res[2]=-99  #this is just a place holder
  res[3]=gden(mx) 
  res[4]=centralization(mx,degree)

  deg = degree(mx, gmode="graph", diag=FALSE, rescale=FALSE)
  res[5]=mean(deg)
  res[6]=sd(deg)
  res[7]=max(deg)
  res[8]=min(deg)

  Ndeg = degree(mx, gmode="graph", diag=FALSE, rescale=TRUE)*1000
  res[9]=mean(Ndeg)
  res[10]=sd(Ndeg)
  res[11]=max(Ndeg)
  res[12]=min(Ndeg)

  iso = isolates(mx, diag=FALSE)
  res[13]=length(iso)

  res[14]=nrow(mx)
}
results=rbind(res)
results
```

Comment: The `rbind` needs to be inside the loop.  There may be other problems, but that is an obvious one.  Also, it needs to be `results=rbind(results, res)`.  Finally, growing a matrix this way isn't fantastic efficiency wise, though with only 81 files you're probably okay.

Answer (score 2):

Make your set of functions together a new function and `sapply` it to every element of `list.files()`:

```
out <- sapply(list.files(), function(i){ 
  nd = read.csv(i, header= TRUE, row.names =1, check.names = FALSE)
  mx = as.matrix(nd)

  res = numeric(14)
  res[1]=basename(i) 
  res[2]=-99  #this is just a place holder
  res[3]=gden(mx) 
  res[4]=centralization(mx,degree)

  deg = degree(mx, gmode="graph", diag=FALSE, rescale=FALSE)
  res[5]=mean(deg)
  res[6]=sd(deg)
  res[7]=max(deg)
  res[8]=min(deg)

  Ndeg = degree(mx, gmode="graph", diag=FALSE, rescale=TRUE)*1000
  res[9]=mean(Ndeg)
  res[10]=sd(Ndeg)
  res[11]=max(Ndeg)
  res[12]=min(Ndeg)

  iso = isolates(mx, diag=FALSE)
  res[13]=length(iso)

  res[14]=nrow(mx)
  return(res)
}
out
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to have rbind(res) inside the loop,something like this
results = rbind(res), but that is not enough. something like results = rbind(results,res)

It depends how you want to store them as an array of array etc..
You'd better also lapply sapply etc.. instead of loop

Answer (score -2):

I also posted this question on my university listserv and a fellow student provided the following fixes. And now it works :)

```
res=(1:14)
summary=(1:14)
for(i in list.files())
{ 
  ....code as above.....

  summary=rbind(summary, res)  
}

summary

# then to put into a .csv
write.csv(summary, "nameoffile.csv")
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution. Building an object sequentially using `rbind` requires R to copy that object in memory each time; in your example creating 14 progressively larger versions of the `summary` object. This will be slow and unnecessary.